# Global feature importance from Linear model Shapley values

Tags: regression

From the original SHAP paper [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.07874) we understand that the Shapley value for a linear model take the form:

$\varphi_i = \beta_i(x_j - \mathbb E[X_j])$

It's easy to check that this formulation satisfies all the usual Shapley Value properties.

However if we want to have a global explanation something weird happen. Let's suppose you want to calculate the mean of the shapley values in your data you woudld get something like

$\mathbb \varphi_i = \mathbb E [\beta_i (x_j - \mathbb E[X_j])] = \beta_i \mathbb [E[x_j] - E[x_j]] = 0$

Does it make any sense?